# Spring Web Client - how to ignore incoming responses?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I am having application that is sending multiple requests (up to 3k/s) using Spring Web Client. Here is example endpoint

```
ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = ConnectionProvider.builder("myConnectionPool")
        .maxConnections(5000)
        .pendingAcquireMaxCount(10000)
        .build();

ReactorClientHttpConnector clientHttpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create(connectionProvider));

WebClient webClient = WebClient
        .builder()
        .clientConnector(clientHttpConnector)
        .build();

@GetMapping(value = "my_endpoint")
public void getSomething(String token) {
    webClient.get()
            .uri(BASE_URL + "/my_endpoint")
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(String.class)
            .onErrorResume(error -> Flux.empty())
            .subscribe();
}
```

The problem I am facing is with memory usage, application sometimes is getting stuck at around 1200-1500 req/s.
I would like to just send what I am about to send and totally ignore response. Just send and forget. Is that possible with Spring web client?
Or maybe my configuration of WebClient is wrong?

Comment: If you want just to ignore the response, remove everything downstream of `retrieve()` and replace it with `.toBodilessEntity()`.  Use `webClient.get().uri(BASE_URL + "/my_endpoint").header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token).retrieve().toBodilessEntity();`

Comment: @lane.maxwell this does not work, receiver service is not getting any requests

Comment: sorry, you still need to do something with the Mono that's returned from the `toBodilessEntity()` call.  You can simply add `.block()`, or you can subscribe to it and get back a ResponseEntity<Void>